# How to cycle through cells in UITableView that have not been visible yet?

Tags: ios, uitableview, first-responder

I am trying to give first responder status to the next table cell of a dynamically generated table, and am doing that by iterating over the tags. That's working well, except when I come to cells that haven't been visible yet and therefore haven't been assigned a tag in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:.

Any idea on how I can assign them a tag or give them the first responder status in any other way?

Comment: Do you know the index path of the cell that you would like to make visible?

Comment: Yes, since it's just the next in line of the current cell, so I can get that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know the index path of your target cell, you can call `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` to bring your cell into the view. Then the `UITableViewCell` will be created in the usual way - through a delegate.

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewCell objects should be reused.  UITableViewCell objects are not reallocated but the content is swapped out with new data.  You can add the ability to your data to determine if they have been placed into a cell.

Comment: But there has to be some way to give focus to a cell that has been invisible so far. Maybe I need to somehow automatically scroll down first so they become visible?

Comment: Sure.  You can scroll to any row with tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath.